# Qt specifying a location for certain application data

Tags: c++, qt

I am making an application in Qt. I have 2 directories, 1 for configurations, the other for program scripts.

I would like to have it say that when I build the project, it will place those directories in a certain directory.

For instance on linux:

```
/home/username/.project_name/configurations
/home/username/.project_name/scripts
```

This should also be cross platform, so on Windows and MacOS these files should be placed in the normal place where application data is stored.

Is there there a way to specify where these directories (and the files in them) should be placed? Is it an option in the project file? And which option ?

Comment: It's kind of weird to place configuration files when you *build*. Wouldn't it make more sense for the application to setup its configuration files and etc. the first time a user *runs* it?

Comment: I guess so. Main point is, how would I be able to specify where to put certain file/directories for an application. Through the Qt Resource system, or some other method.

Answer (score 1):

The qt resource system is used to store files within your application's executable.

You need to answer two questions:

1. Where do the files come from? Does your installer or package contain them, or are they in the executable proper and the application extracts them and saves them. Then the qt resource system is useful.
2. How to get the path you need to create your configuration directory. `QDesktopServices::storageLocation(QDesktopServices::DataLocation)` returns such a path in a cross-platform manner.